# How to get Mac style title bar buttons on Ubuntu gnome without changing rest of the theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, 15.10, macosx, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed arc theme on Ubuntu gnome and I am loving it, but I have one more wish that is to change the close, minimize, maximize buttons' style to that of the Mac OS X Yosemite.

Like this: [image: https://sixcolors.com/images/content/title-bar-edge.jpg]

I want retain the rest of the theme and only change the title bar buttons.

Please do tell if there is a gnome extension to do so. Or is there a work around?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Macbuntu](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html) has bunch of cool packages. You can install parts of it, doesn't have to be whole theme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a perfect theme that satisfies what I need -

Arc Flatabulous:
https://github.com/andreisergiu98/arc-flatabulous-theme

There's also another one with not much differences on gnome-look called OSX-Arc, but the development of Arc-Flatabulous is more active than OSX-Arc

Answer (score 6):

First you will need to find a theme with the buttons you want and install that theme.

You can find many OS X themes at [gnome-look](https://gnome-look.org/), search `gtk3 theme` in the `type` and `osx` in the description, though I will recommend you, based on your question, [this nice flat Yosemite theme](https://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ultra-flat-Yosemite?content=168521) (Developers screenshot).

[image]

This should look really nice with the Arc theme, in my opinion.

Next install

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

When it is finished start this app from the launcher or

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Browse to the `Appearance` section and you will see this

[image]

Change the `window` theme to change your window declarations and `gtk3` for the rest of the theme.

Comment: But which theme should I apply whose window decorations has the Mac style buttons and does not differ much with arc??

Comment: I thought you wanted the window decorations from the arc theme ? Now I see you want arc theme but with the mac style window decorations, updating now.

Comment: If this answer helped, take the time to test it and then please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to find this information easily

Comment: Though I didn't find any themes that matched the darker arc theme

Comment: Doubt there are many dark osx themes, as they copy the osx theme closely and that is a light theme, I did actually find one but it has dark buttons, not the coloured ones of Yosemite and is only gtk2, so won't work on Gnome 3 http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/chris0-OSX-Black?content=73945 I don't think what you want exists. You could try to make it, look in the `Yosemite` themes folder and see if you can make an edit.

Answer (score 3):

i'm using right now a theme from noobslab and they doing a great job, it makes everything to feel like osx!!

Here is the website http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html

if you follow the steps correctly you will have the same exactly result!!